Does $E=mc^2$ suggest $c$ changes over time?
If energy $E$ can neither be created nor destroyed, then presumably there is a constant total E in the universe. Consider E=mc^2. If total E in the universe is constant, then as mass m changes c must also change for the equation to balance. The mass m of the universe is reduced by nuclear fusion in stars with no loss of energy, for example. Also, if the above is true then the speed of light would have been high in the very early universe before massive particles condensed. Let me know why I am wrong, I have little experience with GR.

Relevant to the statement "presumably there is a constant total E in the universe".

https://www.discovermagazine.com/the-sciences/energy-is-not-conserved

Personal theories are off-topic.

There is no way to globally define a stress-energy tensor for the entire spacetime manifold, so the "total energy of the universe" is not a well-defined quantity.

@VincentThacker I don't see how the questioner is promoting a personal theory - this is a perfectly reasonable question that just happens to be based on a misunderstanding of mass-energy equivalence. I am voting to reopen.

Also, I am sure that there are published papers which consider the possibility that the speed of light may have varied over the age of the universe - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_speed_of_light . So I think this question qualifies as mainstream physics.

You have somewhat misunderstood $E=mc^2$. Energy and mass are different ways of measuring the same attribute of physical systems - energy has mass and mass has energy. Let's call this combined attribute mass/energy. We can represent mass/energy in units of mass - say kilogrammes - or we can represent it in units of energy - say Joules. The conversion factor between mass/energy measured in kilogrammes and mass/energy measured in Joules is $c^2$.
Let's sidestep the whole "is the total energy of the universe constant and what does it even mean" question, and think instead about some system that is isolated from its environment. The total mass/energy of that system is constant. In other words the total energy of that system (including the energy represented by what we might conventionally think of as mass) is constant and its total mass (including the mass represented by what we might conventionally think of as energy) is also constant.
In particular, if nuclear reactions take place within that system, they might reduce the conventional mass of the system, and increase its conventional energy by an equivalent amount $E=mc^2$. But the total mass/energy of the system remains constant, and if we represent that total mass/energy in units of mass, that value will be constant (as it will if we represent the total mass/energy in units of energy).

To be fair the OP stated "The mass m of the universe is reduced by nuclear fusion in stars with no loss of energy", meaning he is already aware that the reduction of mass in a star due to fusion does not change the total energy of the system.

There are two misconceptions here. Noether's theorem tells us energy is not always conserved, and this is true for the universe as a whole. Secondly, $E=mc^2$ is a popular abbreviation. The relativistic energy momentum relationship  is actually: $$ E = \sqrt{ (pc)^2 + (mc^2)^2} ,$$ which only reduces to the more well known $E=mc^2$ when there is no motion.
$p$ is the momentum. Photons have momentum proportional to their frequency. When a star undergoes fusion, the mass loss is converted to the energy of the emitted light. This means the overall energy of the star does not change due to the fusion process. It also means the gravitational energy of the star does not change due to the fusion process.
In your question, you are assuming $$E=mc^2 \implies c = \sqrt{\frac{E}{m}}$$ and then concluding: if $E$ is constant and $m$ is reducing, then $c$ must be changing. It is not as simple as that.

It's worth noting though, $E=mc^2$ may have been considered to be accurate in the days when some notations distinguished $m_0$ the rest mass from $m=\gamma m_0$ the relativistic mass. Which is confusing and not standard today, but it does appear in some older textbooks I believe.

@Amit Yes, we can write $E = \sqrt{ (pc)^2 + (m_0c^2)^2} = \sqrt{ (\gamma m_0 v c)^2 + (m_0c^2)^2} $ and this does indeed reduce to $E = \gamma m_0 c^2$ which can be written as simply $E = mc^2$ where m is the relativistic mass. Good point.

Comments of the type "$E=mc^2$ is wrong; the correct is $E=\sqrt{(pc)^2+(mc^2)^2}$" are very common in Physics.SE, but they are seldom helpful. They also miss the core meaning of $E=mc^2,$ that energy has inertia, just like mass.

@md2perpe I have elaborated a bit on the equation. I also linked to the Wikipedia article on the energy momentum relationship which gives a lot more information on the subject if the OP is interested.
